# Fail to install R on linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, r

I am struggling to install R, I am failing over and over again...
At first I just wanted to upgrade from 3.4.4 to 3.4.6 and it failed all the time so I decided to uninstall R completely and install it again.

Know I obtain this

```
$ sudo apt install r-base
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 r-base : Dépend: r-base-core (>= 3.6.2-1disco) mais ne sera pas installé
          Dépend: r-recommended (= 3.6.2-1disco) mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

I am confused, what does it means ?

PS: before this command, I ran

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/'
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Hope anybody can help me !

Comment: Linux Mint 19 is based on Ubuntu-bionic, not disco.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you trying to install with wrong repository.

Ubuntu 19 = Disco Dingo.
But the Linux Mint 19 are based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver). 
[releases and based Linux mint info](https://linuxmint.com/download_all.php)

Remove the repo config (delete a line on /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list) or correct.

Add the key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

And add the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally worked, all this time I didn't remove the line in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list